# Having issues with fetching information from a .yml file in java

Tags: java, yaml, minecraft

I have a piece of spigot code that will create a chest GUI and put items in it. These items can be found in this .yml file:

```
shopSections:
  blocks:
    enable: true
    material: "STONE"
    displayname: "blocks"
    lore: ["Handy for building things :)"]
    place: 13
  weapons:
    enable: true
    material: "IRON_AXE"
    displayname: "Weapons"
    lore: ["Weapons are for awesome people"]
    place: 22
```

However, I need some help fetching the items from it. In short, I need a piece of java code looking like this (i have written this in pseudocode).

```
sections = getFile(sections.yml)
for l in sections {
    if l.getBoolean(enabled) == true {
        gui.createItem(item=l.getString(material),name=l.getString(displayName),place=l.getInt(place))
```

I have attempted to do this quite a few times but the methods i used did not work, so i decided to ask here if people had any suggestions on how to code this. The main issue is that the items inside the list "blocks" have multiple different data types. Any ideas are welcome, thanks.

:)

Answer (score 0):

You're better off relying on an existing YAML parsing library rather than writing your own from scratch. For example, you could check out [SnakeYAML](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml).

Comment: It's quite intuitive, take your time with it and if any doubts arise feel free to raise new, more specific questions about them :) Good luck!